# Transfer code from Colab to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I try to transfer some code from Colab to Jupyter notebook.

The code in Colab is:

```
# Use some functions from tensorflow_docs
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
```

I get the Error:

```
ERROR: Could not detect requirement name for 'git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs', please specify one with #egg=your_package_name"
```

Also if it try it without "!" in the beginning:

```
 pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
```

I get an Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-11-8fda094c7d6e>", line 5
pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: What Python version and what Jupyter version are you using?

Comment: Python: 3.7.5 //  Jupyter Notebook: 6.0.2 //   Tensorflow: 2.0.0

Comment: Can you try with pip3 and also what is the pip3 version?

Comment: If I try with 
    !pip3 install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
i get the Error: Der Befehl "pip3" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

Answer (score 1):

Makes sense that pip without the ! does not work as ! is used to invoke the bash shell within the Jupyter iPython environment.

I tried in a Google Cloud Platform Notebook (Jupyter Lab Version 1.1.4) the command using a Python version (Python 3.5.3):

```
!pip3 install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs --user
```

and worked perfectly.

```
!pip3 freeze | grep tensorflow
```

```
tensorflow==1.15.0
tensorflow-datasets==1.2.0
tensorflow-docs==0.0.0
tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1
tensorflow-hub==0.6.0
tensorflow-io==0.8.0
tensorflow-metadata==0.15.0
tensorflow-probability==0.8.0
tensorflow-serving-api==1.14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also if it try it without "!" in the beginning:

You need to ! in the beginning if you're trying to run a bash command. Otherwise, Jupyter will try to run it as python, which won't work.

Do you have any other code in your notebook? When I tried the code below in the most recent version of Colab and python3, it worked for me:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
```

produced:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
Cloning https://github.com/tensorflow/docs to /tmp/pip-req-build-mrqr1fk8
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/tensorflow/docs /tmp/pip-req-build-mrqr1fk8
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tensorflow-docs==0.0.0 from git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: astor in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-docs==0.0.0) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-docs==0.0.0) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-docs==0.0.0) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-docs==0.0.0) (2.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow-docs==0.0.0) (3.13)
Building wheels for collected packages: tensorflow-docs
  Building wheel for tensorflow-docs (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for tensorflow-docs: filename=tensorflow_docs-0.0.0-cp36-none-any.whl size=80507 sha256=bb4cb3656cd0f5954db502b9812d3ddd49cd1186042a300813874cf1ad84fd3f
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-yl2quvxi/wheels/eb/1b/35/fce87697be00d2fc63e0b4b395b0d9c7e391a10e98d9a0d97f
Successfully built tensorflow-docs
```

Have you tried resetting your runtime and running the code again? Do you have anything else in your notebook?

Answer (score 0):

To find the problem I made a new environment with Anaconda prompt with the following lines:

```
conda create -n regression=3.7
conda activate regression
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name regression --display-name "regression"
conda install tensorflow-gpu
pip install keras
```

Than I activated the environment "regression" and started jupyter notebook

The code I will use is from here: [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression)

I tried it again:

```
# Use seaborn for pairplot
!pip install -q seaborn
```

That works. But when I execute:

```
# Use some functions from tensorflow_docs
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
```

I get now the Error:

"  ERROR: Error [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/tensorflow/docs 'C:\Users\MASTER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-n2je0pjv'
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?
"

With the code:

```
!pip3 install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
```

I get the error:
"Der Befehl "pip3" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden."

Comment: As error says do you have git installed? if you try to clone a repo does it work? Example: !git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples.git

Comment: Does not work: Error: "Der Befehl "git" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden. "Translation: "The command "git" is either misspelled or could not be found." How can I install git?

Comment: Oh no, and I was searching for git installation via anaconda :|   I have now installed it from this site https://git-scm.com/downloads and it works now after a new activation of the environment! Thank you and shame on me